# Exchange 2016 keeps giving away it's default Self-signed certificate instead of CA one

Tags: exchange

I've got Exchange 2016 server being prepared for it's prime time. But Outlook client, connected to mailbox on that server, pops out window saying that certificate issued by not trusted organization, more specifically - it's default self-signed certificate, which was created during Exchange installation.

The problem is that I've created and installed proper SSL certificate with domain CA, assigned it to services and to IIS, but server keeps giving it's SS certificate for some reason.

Output of **Get-ExchangeCertificate | Format-List FriendlyName,Subject,CertificateDomains,Thumbprint,Services**

```
FriendlyName       : CA Certificate for HTTPS
Subject            : CN=web.contoso.com, OU=IT, O=The Contoso, L=Almaty, S=Almaty, C=KZ
CertificateDomains : {web.contoso.com, mail.contoso.com, AutoDiscover.contoso.com, bsb-srv-mb-exch.contoso.com, BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH, 
                     contoso.com}
Thumbprint         : 8-4
Services           : IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP

FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange
Subject            : CN=BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
CertificateDomains : {BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH, BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH.contoso.com}
Thumbprint         : 6-7
Services           : IMAP, POP, SMTP

FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
Subject            : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
CertificateDomains : {}
Thumbprint         : 8-6
Services           : SMTP

FriendlyName       : WMSVC
Subject            : CN=WMSvc-BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
CertificateDomains : {WMSvc-BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH}
Thumbprint         : F-0
Services           : None
```

It also does very same thing when I use my browser to connect https to server - keeps warning me about SS certificate instead of CA one. How can I make it use proper certificate?

Comment: What's the output of `Get-ExchangeCertificate | Format-List FriendlyName,Subject,CertificateDomains,Thumbprint,Services RootCAType, Issuer, IsSelfSigned`?

Answer (score 0):

Shinjijai,
Here is the output:

```
FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange
Subject            : CN=BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
CertificateDomains : {BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH, BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH.contoso.com}
Thumbprint         : 9-9
Services           : IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP
RootCAType         : None
Issuer             : CN=BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
IsSelfSigned       : True

FriendlyName       : CA Certificate for HTTPS 2
Subject            : CN=contoso.com, OU=IT Department, O=The Contoso, L=Almaty, S=Almaty, C=KZ
CertificateDomains : {contoso.com, web.contoso.com, mail.contoso.com, AutoDiscover.contoso.com, bsb-srv-mb-exch.contoso.com}
Thumbprint         : C-6
Services           : IIS, SMTP
RootCAType         : Enterprise
Issuer             : CN=contoso-SERVER1-CA, DC=contoso, DC=com
IsSelfSigned       : False

FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
Subject            : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
CertificateDomains : {}
Thumbprint         : 8-6
Services           : SMTP
RootCAType         : None
Issuer             : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
IsSelfSigned       : True

FriendlyName       : WMSVC
Subject            : CN=WMSvc-BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
CertificateDomains : {WMSvc-BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH}
Thumbprint         : F-0
Services           : None
RootCAType         : Registry
Issuer             : CN=WMSvc-BSB-SRV-MB-EXCH
IsSelfSigned       : True
```

Anyway, I've managed to fix it somehow. You see, it was second time installation of Exchange 2016 on same instance of OS. So one time there were two Self-Signed certificates for Exchange: one from previous installation, and one from current. I've noticed back then that for some reason new instance of Exchange were using certificate from previous one, instead of it's own. So I've removed first certificate. Guess some hidden from UI assignments were broken by removal of extra SS-certificate.

And my problem were fixed by removal CA-certificate and adding new one. After that Exchange seems to recognize that it has more appropriate certificate then SS one. So now it supplies proper certificate to clients.